# Issue Insert Into (BigTable1) SELECT From (BiggerTable2)

Tags: select, insert

I am selecting a set of data from a bigTable1 (index-ed) and then inserting them into another bigTable2 (index-ed)

I have two options: Which is a good idea:

Option:  1

```
INSERT INTO bigTable2 (bigTable2.Col1, bigTable2.Col2)
SELECT bigTable1.Col1, bigTable1.Col2 FROM bigTable1 (nolock)
WHERE  bigTable1.col3 between @value1 and @value2
```

Option:  2

```
CREATE #TEMP (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(200))

INSERT INTO #TEMP (Col1, Col2)
SELECT bigTable1.Col1, bigTable1.Col2 FROM bigTable1 (nolock)
WHERE bigTable1.col3 between @value1 and @value2

INSERT INTO bigTable2 (bigTable2.Col1, bigTable2.Col2)
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM #TEMP
```

I do not want to lock the bigTable1. Please advise which one is the better one between the two? Is there any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lock the table, then go with the first approach. It's a one-step procedure and, no matter how long it takes, you keep the table unlocked, so you don't block others.

The second option would be appropriate in case you *wanted* the table locked during the select. Having to fill an empty, non-indexed table would be faster, thus keeping your table locked for a shorter period.